# How to set VM parameters at run time in install4j

Tags: runtime, virtual-machine, startup, install4j

How can we set VM parameters at runtime based on condition or in startup action or is there is any way to set VM parameters at runtime??

Answer (score 1):

There is an "Add VM options" action in install4j for that purpose.

It adds VM parameters to the .vmoptions file of the selected launcher.